Error Running ParaView on WSL: "spirv-expand-step" Registered More Than Once
I'm experiencing an issue when trying to run ParaView on WSL (Ubuntu 22.04). Every time I attempt to launch the application, it fails with the following error:
: CommandLine Error: Option 'spirv-expand-step' registered more than once!LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options

Loguru caught a signal: SIGABRT 
Stack trace:
55      0x56464c07c3f5 paraview(+0xd3f5) [0x56464c07c3f5]
54      0x7f63bd70fe40 __libc_start_main + 128
53      0x7f63bd70fd90 /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7f63bd70fd90]
52      0x56464c07b04c paraview(+0xc04c) [0x56464c07b04c]
51      0x7f63bcf03ebe QWidgetPrivate::setVisible(bool) + 126
50      0x7f63bcef6b1e QWidget::create(unsigned long long, bool, bool) + 238
49      0x7f63bcef64f5 QWidgetPrivate::create() + 613
48      0x7f63bc23fb21 QWindowPrivate::create(bool, unsigned long long) + 161
47      0x7f63a0ac5636 QXcbIntegration::createPlatformWindow(QWindow*) const + 342
46      0x7f63a0ad9025 QXcbWindow::create() + 4389
45      0x7f639e09e7d3 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so(+0x97d3) [0x7f639e09e7d3]
44      0x7f639c69fadc /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0(+0x32adc) [0x7f639c69fadc]
43      0x7f639c6a2fd0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0(+0x35fd0) [0x7f639c6a2fd0]
42      0x7f639c69d143 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0(+0x30143) [0x7f639c69d143]
41      0x7f637cfe2266 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xbf266) [0x7f637cfe2266]
40      0x7f637cfd8ef0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xb5ef0) [0x7f637cfd8ef0]
39      0x7f637d62f5e7 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0x70c5e7) [0x7f637d62f5e7]
38      0x7f637d62f6a6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0x70c6a6) [0x7f637d62f6a6]
37      0x7f637cfd85f0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xb55f0) [0x7f637cfd85f0]
36      0x7f637dacf85a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xbac85a) [0x7f637dacf85a]
35      0x7f637dacf5ac /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xbac5ac) [0x7f637dacf5ac]
34      0x7f637dad09ef /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xbad9ef) [0x7f637dad09ef]
33      0x7f6384efb963 /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12core.so(+0x318963) [0x7f6384efb963]
32      0x7f6384f42e40 /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12core.so(+0x35fe40) [0x7f6384f42e40]
31      0x7f6384f41489 /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12core.so(+0x35e489) [0x7f6384f41489]
30      0x7f6384f40880 /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12core.so(+0x35d880) [0x7f6384f40880]
29      0x7f6384f40b2c /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12core.so(+0x35db2c) [0x7f6384f40b2c]
28      0x7f63850116a8 /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12core.so(+0x42e6a8) [0x7f63850116a8]
27      0x7f6385025781 /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12core.so(+0x442781) [0x7f6385025781]
26      0x7f639c5ef35f OpenAdapter12 + 175
25      0x7f639c5ef56e /usr/lib/wsl/drivers/iigd_dch.inf_amd64_df02d1089288b40d/libigd12umd64.so(+0x156e) [0x7f639c5ef56e]
24      0x7f63843fd9ad /usr/lib/wsl/drivers/iigd_dch.inf_amd64_df02d1089288b40d/libigd12um64xel.so(+0x309ad) [0x7f63843fd9ad]
23      0x7f6384475673 /usr/lib/wsl/drivers/iigd_dch.inf_amd64_df02d1089288b40d/libigd12um64xel.so(+0xa8673) [0x7f6384475673]
22      0x7f638449be8d /usr/lib/wsl/drivers/iigd_dch.inf_amd64_df02d1089288b40d/libigd12um64xel.so(+0xcee8d) [0x7f638449be8d]
21      0x7f63bd7766c8 dlopen + 72
20      0x7f63bd77612e /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x9012e) [0x7f63bd77612e]
19      0x7f63bd85ab63 _dl_catch_error + 51
18      0x7f63bd85aa98 _dl_catch_exception + 136
17      0x7f63bd77663c /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x9063c) [0x7f63bd77663c]
16      0x7f63bd91f34e /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0xe34e) [0x7f63bd91f34e]
15      0x7f63bd85aa98 _dl_catch_exception + 136
14      0x7f63bd91eff6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0xdff6) [0x7f63bd91eff6]
13      0x7f63bd85aaf5 _dl_catch_exception + 229
12      0x7f63bd917568 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x6568) [0x7f63bd917568]
11      0x7f63bd91747e /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x647e) [0x7f63bd91747e]
10      0x7f6364d14c23 /usr/lib/wsl/drivers/iigd_dch.inf_amd64_df02d1089288b40d/libigc.so(+0x270c23) [0x7f6364d14c23]
9       0x7f63650f798b /usr/lib/wsl/drivers/iigd_dch.inf_amd64_df02d1089288b40d/libigc.so(+0x65398b) [0x7f63650f798b]
8       0x7f63575b9be0 llvm::cl::Option::addArgument() + 26
7       0x7f63575b9b5b /usr/lib/wsl/drivers/iigd_dch.inf_amd64_df02d1089288b40d/libLLVM-14.so(+0x719b5b) [0x7f63575b9b5b]
6       0x7f63575b980f /usr/lib/wsl/drivers/iigd_dch.inf_amd64_df02d1089288b40d/libLLVM-14.so(+0x71980f) [0x7f63575b980f]
5       0x7f63575cbf9c /usr/lib/wsl/drivers/iigd_dch.inf_amd64_df02d1089288b40d/libLLVM-14.so(+0x72bf9c) [0x7f63575cbf9c]
4       0x7f63575cbee9 llvm::report_fatal_error(llvm::Twine const&, bool) + 383
3       0x7f63bd70e7f3 abort + 211
2       0x7f63bd728476 raise + 22
1       0x7f63bd77c9fc pthread_kill + 300
0       0x7f63bd728520 /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520) [0x7f63bd728520](   1.492s) [paraview        ]                       :0     FATL| Signal: SIGABRTAborted

Despite multiple reinstalls, the problem persists. Has anyone encountered this issue before or knows how to fix it?

I recently encountered this problem. The issue seems to have been caused by having multiple instances of wsl running. In my case caused by docker. You can check this by running the folowing command in PowerShell
wsl --list

and if you get more than one instances, you can attempt to unregister them using
wsl --unregister docker-desktop

where you would replace docker-desktop with the one you like to unregister.
